# How can I host my CSS/JS on an HTTPS server

Tags: javascript, css, https

I am facing problems with loading my custom CSS in Chrome. I'm using Joomla Artforms.

Here are few Javascript console statements from chrome:

[blocked] The page at 'https://www.mysite.com/component/artforms/?formid=200' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http:// www.mysite.com/includes/js/jscalendar-1.0/calendar_stripped.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

[blocked] The page at 'https:// www.mysite.com/component/artforms/?formid=200' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http: //www.mysite.com/modules/mod_followme/style.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Please let me know if you need more detail.

Thanks

Comment: We don't need more detail, if your site uses SSL and runs on https, you should only include files that also uses that protocol

Comment: Read the error messages. They aren't cryptic: *The page at ... was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from ...: this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.*

Comment: This is a lame question but; How can I load css over https? Can you state me the steps of the process. Thanks

Comment: How to enable HTTPS for your static resources? any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to get this right is to load external files using the URL syntax

> //example.com/path/to/some/file.js (remote)

or

> /path/to/some/file.js (local)

This will load your resource using the same protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) as your main HTML page.

Note though that this will only work if your external resource is available over HTTPS. If it isn't then there's nothing you can do except move the external resource somewhere that does support HTTPS.

Comment: How to enable HTTPS for your static resources? any suggestion?

Comment: That's a webserver configuration question best asked on ServerFault however if you can serve your HTML as HTTPS then there shouldnt be any reason your static files wont work as well