# How to enable HTTPS for your static resources?

Tags: javascript, css, https

I am new to web development and facing problems with loading my custom CSS/JS in https pages.
I have tried changing the url as follow but still have the same problem.

`//example.com/path/to/some/file.js` (remote)

`/path/to/some/file.js` (local)

Javascript Console Statement:

> [blocked] The page at 'https:// www.mysite.com/component/artforms/?formid=200' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http: //www.mysite.com/modules/mod_followme/style.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

So is their any easy way to enable HTTPS for static resources? either from joomla admin or from cpanel.

Cheers

Comment: Assuming you have an SSL certificate and a server set up, you serve the files over https, and use https:// when referencing them on your site ?

Comment: I have also tried like
"https: //www.mysite.com/modules/mod_followme/style.css"
but still chrome blocked my css. But it works while giving reference from dropbox public folder.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. View the source of the page and search for URLs beginning with `http://`. Or look at the warnings in console; on the right hand side you will find filename+line number where the reference to `http://` url was found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I host my CSS/JS on an HTTPS server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462685/how-can-i-host-my-css-js-on-an-https-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check this 2 points :

### URL construction

- if your main page is already in https (https://example.com/index.html), and your URL is relative,

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/some/file.js"></script>,`

`result =  https://example.com/path/to/some/file.js`

- if your main page is already in https (https://example.com/index.html), and your URL contains protocol and hostname part, check protocol is corerct --> https
- if you use frame or iframe, check URL of frame include your resource "path/to/some/file.js"

### Server configuration

Check you have the same configuration for "component/artforms/" and "component/artforms/" .

For joomla config : https://www.sslmatrix.com/blog/how-to-enable-ssl-in-joomla#001

Comment: Hi Geurti, I main domain is not in https (its a mixed http/https site). I am just using https for artforms in joomla. I have tried and changed the links as you stated above; but same result :(.

Answer (score 0):

For enabling Https you need to get a Certificate,some hosting providers set those either automatically or they may charge.And then you need to configure your Application server for a SSL.

Comment: Had checked with http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
ssl is installed perfectly.